# How to find order-preserving subsequence in C#?

Tags: c#

What I want to do is find subsequences in a given sequence. But I want the subsequence method to be different. Namely, first digits should always come first, second always second, and so on. So, it should be order preserving.

For example given three integers, X = 100, Y = 350, Z = 35, I want to find all the numbers between X and Y, such that the numbers digits contain the sequence of Z digits, namely {3, 5}. The output in this case should be 8 and the subsequences are: 135, 235, 305, 315, 325, 335, 345, 350.

```
public List<int> split(int Z) {

    var digits = new List<int>();

    for (; Z > 0; Z /= 10) {
        digits.Add(Z % 10);
    }

    return digits;
}

private static int count(int X, int Y, int Z) {

    int count = 0;
    var splitZ = split(Z);

    for (int i = X; i <= Y; i++) {
        var idigits = split(i); 
        var subseq = new LinkedList<int>();

        foreach (var digit in idigits) {
            subseq.AddLast(digit);

            if (subseq.Count == splitZ.Count) {
                if (subseq.SequenceEqual(splitZ)) {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I have the above code segment, but the problem with it is that, it returns as output 3 instead of 8. It just counts, 135, 235, 335. Where sequence 35 is next to each other. Any ideas how to modify the code and achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you looked at the radix sort?

Comment: that reminds me of logic semester 1 - DFAs and NFAs

Comment: @DavidLively Not really no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your logic a bit. See the in-code comments for explanation.

```
private static int count(int X, int Y, int Z)
{

    int count = 0;
    var splitZ = split(Z);

    if (splitZ.Count == 0)
    {
        return Y - X + 1; // everything matches an empty Z sequence
    }

    for (int i = X; i <= Y; i++)
    {
        var idigits = split(i);
        int subIndex = 0;

        foreach (var digit in idigits)
        {
            if (splitZ[subIndex] == digit)
            {
                ++subIndex; // matched digit
            }

            if (subIndex >= splitZ.Count)
            {
                ++count;
                break; // matched whole sub-sequence
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.